# How to keep y axis range the same regardless of filters used in my power bi dashboard?

Tags: powerbi

I have created a column chart in power bi. Depending on the filters selected in my graph, the column chart changes values. But also the y axis changes. So if 50 is the biggest value in my dataset the y axis will also only go to 50 rather than staying at the number it was prior to filtering. Is there a way I can fix this?

I would like my y axis to be static regardless of the filtering used in my dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your chart visual selected,

- navigate to the visualizations tab on the right
- click the middle icon (histogram with a paintbrush).
- Expand 'Y-Axis' and then 'Range'
- set the minimum/maximum to the intended values